# How to create an instance of a form from a template

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have several forms with multiple controls (customers, orders, comments ect.). I want to automate them and I'm creating a class that will manage form contents in general.
So each object of UIForm class should be associated with with a separate instance of a particular form. I'm trying to pass formName and create a form object inside like this:

'class manages common works with database forms (clients, orders, comments)

```vb
Public Class UForm
    Public UIForm As Form
    Public Sub createUIForm(ByVal FormTemplate As Form)
        UIForm = New FormTemplate()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The question is how to pass a form template as a parameter. May be you know how to make it in a more elegant way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you've posted, I'm not seeing what benefit that class provides but I'll assume that there is something about it you haven't shown us that is beneficial. It may well be that you could make the class generic:

```vb
Public Class UForm(Of TForm As {New, Form})

    Public Property UiForm As TForm

    Public Sub CreateUiForm()
        UiForm = New TForm()
    End Sub

End Class
```

That means that each instance can only handle one type of form though, like this:

```vb
Dim uf As New UForm(Of Form1)

uf.CreateUiForm()
```

If you genuinely need to be able to pass the name of a form type, which is what you said you want to do, then you'd have to use Reflection:

```vb
Public Class UForm

    Public Property UiForm As Form

    Public Sub CreateUiForm(formTypeName As String)
        Dim formType = Type.GetType(formTypeName)
        Dim constructor = formType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)
        Dim instance = constructor.Invoke(Nothing)

        UiForm = DirectCast(instance, Form)
    End Sub

End Class
```

In that case, you need to provide the fully qualified name of the form class, e.g.

```vb
Dim uf As New UForm

uf.CreateUiForm("SomeNamespace.SomeForm")
```

This is all possible but highly irregular. I'm still not seeing what benefit such a class provides but this does answer the question as asked.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! That is beautiful and very helpful explanation- works as a charm!!!